# Retrieve Git file commit messages

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I have a Git repository and I would like to retrieve all commit messages of a specific file. I also would like to see how a file looked at a specific commit.

So in pseudo code:

- Get all commits of a file (already implemented)
- Retrieve file content of a specific commit

I am using the ['ReactiveUI'](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) (as test) repository and the next code to retrieve the commits of a specific file. In this case the Activation.cs file.

```
Repository repo = new Repository(@"D:\Test\ReactiveUI");

IEnumerable<LogEntry> history = repo.Commits.QueryBy(@"ReactiveUI\Activation.cs").ToList();
```

If I compare the history.Count() value 12 with the amount of messages I see with TortoiseGit (right click on the file + show log) 35, there is a difference.

Could you explain what is wrong with the implementation? What code do I need to add/ modify?

Thank you in advance!

*[Source of the test code](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FileHistoryFixture.cs#L47)

Comment: Do `history.Count()` and `Tortoisegit's show log` work on the same branch?

Comment: I assume that they both work on the same branch, because the repo.Commits contains the same amount of messages as Tortoise Git. (right click on the repository + show log)

Comment: Right now I'm wondering that myself, why it returns something different compared to git log ...